# How to change text in TextInput field after a user picks a label from RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I am developing a transportation app using Kivy and Python. There is a TextInput field where the user starts typing the name of a departure stop. On text input, a RecycleView with selectable departure stops names will be displayed. After the user clicks on a departure stop name, the name of the departure stop should be copied to the TextInput field and the RecycleView should disappear until the user starts typing in the field again.

Right now, **I don't know how to copy the departure stop name chosen by the user within the RecycleView to the text input field.**

A sample of search_trip.kv:

```
<MatchedStops>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    DepartureStopName:
        id: departure_stop
        hint_text: "Departure stop"
        multiline: False
        on_text:
            root.find_stop(departure_stop.text)

    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
        data: [{'text': str(x["stop_name"])} for x in root.stops_data]
        SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            default_size: None, dp(26)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
```

A sample of search_trip.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (
    ScreenManager,
    Screen,
    NoTransition,
)

from search_stops.search import match_stop

Builder.load_file("search_trip.kv")

class TransportSearchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        screen_manager.add_widget(TripSearchScreen(name="search_trip_screen"))
        return screen_manager


class TripSearchScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MatchedStops(BoxLayout):
    stops_data = ListProperty([])
    departure_stop_name = ObjectProperty()

    def find_stop(self, stop: str) -> None:
        matched_stops = match_stop(stop)
        self.stops_data = matched_stops

    def fill_departure_stop_name(self, dept_stop_name):
        self.ids.departure_stop.text = dept_stop_name


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleGridLayout):
    """ Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. """


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    """Add selection support to the Label"""

    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """Catch and handle the view changes"""
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        """Add selection on touch down"""
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        """Respond to the selection of items in the view."""
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected and rv.data[index]["text"] != "None":
            matched_stops = MatchedStops()
            matched_stops.departure_stop_name = rv.data[index]["text"]
            matched_stops.fill_departure_stop_name(rv.data[index]["text"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TransportSearchApp().run()
```

I believe I may need to edit the text input directly on the `DepartureStopName` class, i.e. do something like:

```
class DepartureStopName(TextInput):
    text = StringProperty()

    def update_stop_name(self, txt):
        self.text = txt
```

But I didn't manage to get that going either - in that case, the text input field was always empty and the RecycleView wasn't shown at all.